# How to make footer invisible on making screen size smaller?

Tags: html, css

My footer is absolutely fine on a normal screen size but I want it to become invisible when I shrink the screen after a certain height.Any ideas how to do it without using javascript?My HTML and CSS snippets are as follows:

HTML:

```
<footer class="footer">
        About
</footer>
```

CSS:

```
.footer{
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    box-shadow: 0 0 3px white;
    color:white;
}
```

Comment: Take a look at [media queries](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/). They let you show/hide elements depending on screen size, among other things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***[`jsFiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/RjKQ8/)***

Use a max height media query on your page in order to hide the footer. Note that this is compatible in [almost all browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-mediaqueries), except IE8-.

html for demo

```
 <div id="footer">Footer</div>
```

css

```
@media (max-height:150px) {
 #footer{
  display:none;    
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    .footer {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

## [`DEMO`](http://jsfiddle.net/774Av/1/) and [`Source`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/)

Answer (score 0):

Try a media query in your css document like so:

```
media screen and (max-height:700px) {
  .footer {
    display:none;
  }
}
```

Media queries take a lot of different arguments, i.e. min-height, min and max width, etc. [Mozilla dev](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries) covers the operators with great examples.